# I inherit from std::iterator, but compiler does not recognise 'pointer' or 'reference'

Tags: c++, templates, iterator

I am in the process of making a custom iterator, but I am puzzled on
what makes the compiler not recognise the `pointer` or `reference` typedefs in the case of a templated iterator implementation.

The following code compiles fine:

```
#include <iterator>

struct It : std::iterator<std::random_access_iterator_tag, int>
{
    int *v;
    pointer operator-> () { return v; }
    reference operator* () { return *v; }

};
```

but once I templatize my custom iterator I get errors:

```
#include <iterator>

template <class T>
struct It2 : std::iterator<std::random_access_iterator_tag, T>
{
    T *v;
    pointer operator-> () { return v; }
    reference operator* () { return *v; }

};
```

[whole code here](http://cpp.sh/5je3g)

```
error: 'pointer' does not name a type
note: (perhaps 'typename std::iterator<std::random_access_iterator_tag, T>::pointer' was intended)
error: 'reference' does not name a type
...
```

**1> Why can't the compiler see the `pointer` and `reference` definitions contained in the `std::iterator` ?**

According to the `note`, it seems that I shouldn't have bothered using the std::iterator struct, but instead I should have manually copied the typedefs.
But that seems too error prone in case the iterator or iterator_traits get an extra typedef in the future.

**2. How do you think I should deal with the definition of these traits (`pointer`, `reference` etc.) ?**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/610245/560648

Comment: @GrimFandango I'm sorely tempted to correct your misspelling in the title. It's like you can't speak `Merican ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 1> Why can't the compiler see the pointer and reference definitions contained in the std::iterator ?

Because the compiler cannot rule out you attempting to provide a specialisation of `std::iterator` where `pointer` and `reference` aren't type definitions, dependent names can never be interpreted as a `typedef` at template definition time.

> 2. How do you think I should deal with the definition of these traits (pointer, reference etc.) ?

While explicitly qualifying them with `typename` every time works, what you can do instead is declare them once as such, and rely on that one declaration in the rest of your `It2` definition:

```
#include <iterator>

template <class T>
struct It2 : std::iterator<std::random_access_iterator_tag, T>
{
    using base = std::iterator<std::random_access_iterator_tag, T>;
    using typename base::pointer;
    using typename base::reference;
    T *v;
    pointer operator-> () { return v; }
    reference operator* () { return *v; }
};
```

Comment: agree. I use this style for all superclasses. It's slightly safer if you make the aliased type `base` private.

Answer (score 5):

Now that your base class is a [dependent type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/610245/560648), so are its members `pointer` and `reference`.

You need to:

- indicate to the compiler that those words are types
- indicate to the compiler that those words are member types

You can do it easily:

```
   typename It2::pointer operator-> () { return v; }
   typename It2::reference operator* () { return *v; }
// ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Why? Because C++ is quirky as frak and extremely inexpressive.

Comment: Downvotes? [**TRY IT YOURSELF**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f99d21add5dcdbc4)

Comment: or more accurately, "why? Because how can the compiler otherwise know you *meant* an inherited type?  You could have meant some type in the current namespace, a parent namespace or the global namespace."

Comment: @RichardHodges: No other language is so weakly constructed so as to require this mess :P

Comment: @RichardHodges I don't know; how does the compiler know in the first case ? Koenig lookup rules for namespace, but what about global namespace ?

Comment: Is there another language that supports the same range of conceptual expressions in a compile-time type-safe way? This is a genuine question.

Comment: @RichardHodges: _Any_ functional programming language, for starters?

Comment: specifically which one? templates in Haskell are problematic are they not?

Comment: @Richard: Who said anything about templates? But we're going wildly off-topic now.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit um, the question was about templates wasn't it? :-)

Comment: @RichardHodges: What must be implemented using templates in C++ may be implemented another way in not-C++. You cannot automatically compare like-for-like (which is, indeed, the point). You asked me about another language with the same range of conceptual expressions in a compile-time type-safe way, not one which does so using C++'s notion of templates.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is very clear about the error:

> **perhaps `typename std::iterator<std::random_access_iterator_tag, T>::pointer` was intended**

because `pointer` has become a type-dependent name.

Comment: It's not clear to anyone _why_ "perhaps ... was intended" until explained.

Comment: if clang did not provide this alternative, I'd be stuck. Now, I was just puzzled on what is the best way to declare the `operators`